# Распорядок в z-index'ах

Tags: html, css, z-index

Вроде бы все нормально расставлено, а на практике наоборот.
При загрузке страницы и открытии мобильного (!) меню, его пункты оказываются под слайдером, но при изменении положения, когда срабатывает фиксация (сверху окна все время), то все отлично.
Был бы этот баг незаметен или труднонаходимым, однако, при заходе на сайт часто требуется сразу же воспользоваться меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Сам сайт: dsz.zzz.com.ua**

Есть еще один баг, но он уже труднодоступный, заключается в том, что при открытии мобильного меню и увеличении окна браузера backgroung ломается.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл z-index - чем больше значение тем выше/виднее.
В вашем случае достаточно

```
#nav {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Еще у вас слайдер сыпет ошибки, посмотрите апи bxslider'а и посмотрите классы

Comment: С z-index есть тонкости, Он учитывает иерархию вложенности блоков. Новички часто встречаются с ошибкой, когда элемент с большим z-index перекрывается сверху эл. с меньшим z-index и думают, что это какая-то мистика. Реалии в том, что у них оказывается какой-нибудь родительский блок с выставленным z-index, который нарушает логику работы этого свойства у детей.

Comment: @Олег Суворов, я не шарю с api, а вот по поводу классов, то ты имеешь в виду пересечение одинаковых названий? larrymacbarry, тоже вероятно, но я проходился с самого начала по стилям для слайдера и ничего не видел, даже скажу больше, вводил в поиск z-index и искал, в чем может быть несовпадение. Там их использовалось всего 2-3, их я перекрыл, чтобы меню было сверху, а вот вызов самого меню не хочет поддаваться.